# Mapbox marker styles are not applied

Tags: css, ionic-framework, mapbox

I'm trying to implement Mapbox in an Ionic 5 application.
I initialize my map with

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: this.style,
  zoom: 13,
  center: [this.lng, this.lat]
});

this.initPosition();
}
```

and then i set a marker with

```
setMarker() {
const el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'marker';
this.marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat([this.lng, this.lat])
    .addTo(this.map);
}
```

my styles.scss:

```
#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;

}

.marker { //this is just for testing, i know it looks horrible
  background-color: red;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 61px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;

}
```

and my html:

```
<div id='map'></div>
```

The map shows up correctly, and I can see the marker in the developer console. However, my styles are not applied. If I apply styles manually to `.mapboxgl-marker {` in developer console, it still doesnt show up, but once I remove the transform property, the marker is in the top left corner of the map, but not where it is supposed to be.

This is driving me crazy

Comment: are you correctly setting the position? if you zoom out at the maximum level do you see the marker?

Comment: apparently not. if I zoom out completely, AND set the styles manually, I do see the marker on the other side of the world. I'm passing an array of [lng, lat].  How do i set the position correctly? And styles are still not applied, I need to set them manually in developer console

Comment: then clear your cache, this is probably the issue of your styles

Comment: Nope, styles are still not applied

Comment: I found a workaround for styling with: el.setAttribute('style', 'width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: red');
But the position is still completely wrong. Why can't i set it with [lng, lat]?

Comment: you have a link where we can see the map live ?

Comment: Nevermind, I updated the variables after setting the marker. Think this will be fine with this workaround for the styling issue.